# Is it possible to export CR's to csv from the command line with StarTeam 2009?

Tags: starteam

I want to be able to
[export change requests](http://kb.microfocus.com/display/4/kb/article.aspx?aid=35003&n=1&docid=18030043&tab=search) from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for StarTeam 2009 and earlier, the Command-Line tool (stcmd)
is designed for automating your build process
by allowing you to checkout a set of files in order to build them.
(it also supports checking-in files, but the tool is mostly for checking-out files).

To extract the content of CRs, you can either use a **Report** (via the UI),
or you can write something in Java that will utilize the **StarTeam SDK** for that.

Comment: Just a note that you can also use C#/VB.Net to program against the StarTeam SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted indicated that a command line option for this is not available.  That statement was accurate through StarTeam 11.0, but is no longer the case.  The latest version of StarTeam now has a new command line client which will allow you to use SQL-like queries, so you can now SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE items directly.  This means an export is now natively supported by StarTeam.  This also gives you a new option to be able to import new items using INSERT; however, your biggest challenges are data field mapping (do you have the right status, severity, etc. and are the field names mapped correctly), and workflow support (does the current state of the data comply with the workflow rules you have defined, assuming you are using a custom APE to support CR workflows).

It is also worth noting that the **Report** option listed above is not the best option for this via the UI, as there is an **Advanced --> Export** option that allows you to export all of the selected/filtered items in the top pane into a CSV file.  My guess is that this approach would be a better alternative to the Report option, which has limited formatting options and produces output that would be very difficult to use in anything but a printed form.